# "Retreat" in XML with Xpath expression

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I define the parent path of the map attributes to `#{@root}/items/home`, but I have a special case. The xpath would be `#{@root}/notes`

Can I "retreat" in a xpath like this:  `xpath: '../notes'` (For some reasons, I don't want to change my parent path)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `XPath axes parent`, like this: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=49v&q=xpath+axes+parent

Then try `parent::*[1]/notes` to make an XPath query that retreats one step.

Comment: It worked for the wrong reason; because an XPath that starts with '//' goes back to the document root and searches again, disregarding the current context. But whatever floats your boat...